# How can we upload Directory/fileList to s3 with SSEKMSkeyID using java?

Tags: java

```
public void transferList(List<File> list) {
    String key;
    String bucketName;
    String sseKmsKeyId;
    AmazonS3 amazonS3;
    TransferManager xfermgr;
    try {
        amazonS3 = "";
        key = "";
        bucketName = "";
        sseKmsKeyId = "";
        xfermgr = new TransferManager(amazonS3);
    }
    try {
        ObjectMetadataProvider objectMetadataProvider = new ObjectMetadataProvider() {
            @Override
            public void provideObjectMetadata(File file, ObjectMetadata metadata) {
                // metadata.setSSEAlgorithm("aws:kms"); 
                // metadata.setSSECustomerAlgorithm(sseKmsKeyId); 
                // metadata.setServerSideEncryption(sseKmsKeyId); //  
                metadata.setSSEAlgorithm(sseAwsKeyManagementParams.getAwsKmsKeyId());
            }
        }; // ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata(); //  
        objectMetadata.setSSEAlgorithm(sseKmsKeyId);
        LOGGER.info("uploaded file = {} {} {} ", bucketName, key, new File(".").getAbsoluteFile());
        MultipleFileUpload dirUpload = xfermgr.uploadFileList(bucketName, key, list.get(0).getParentFile(), list);
        dirUpload.waitForCompletion();
    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
        throw new AmazonServiceException(e);
    }
}
```

---

```
MultipleFileUpload dirUpload = xfermgr.uploadFileList(bucketName, key, list.get(0).getParentFile(), list);
```

how can we upload kmskey using MultipleFileUpload

Comment: MultipleFileUpload dirUpload = xfermgr.uploadFileList(bucketName, key, list.get(0).getParentFile(), list);  how can we upload kmskey using MultipleFileUpload

Answer (score 0):

```
    ObjectMetadataProvider objectMetadataProvider = new ObjectMetadataProvider() {
        @Override
        public void provideObjectMetadata(File file, ObjectMetadata metadata) {
            metadata.setSSEAlgorithm(sseAwsKeyManagementParams.getEncryption()); // will always be your aws:kms
            metadata.setHeader(
                Headers.SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION_AWS_KMS_KEYID,
                sseAwsKeyManagementParams.getAwsKmsKeyId()
        );
        }
    };
```

You were missing the Header you have to set in the metadata and always use the setSSEAlgorithm (the setSSECustomerAlgorithm is for internal use and not for the request).

Above all that you should have your :

```
final SSEAwsKeyManagementParams sseAwsKeyManagementParams = new SSEAwsKeyManagementParams(KMS_KEY_GOES_HERE);
```

which will hold your KMS key in the request.

Good luck.